# Angular - scripts load order

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've just started with Angular after many years working with MVC. I'm quite familiar with js, HMTL but still beginner in the Angular world.

I lost 3 hours trying to figure out what is wrong with my app.

So the app has 3 files

index.html

```
 <body ng-app="perica">

        <p>main</p>
        {{ tagline }}
        <a ng-click="logOut();">Logout</a>
        <div ng-view><p>inside</p></div>


    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../AgularApp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../controllers/AcountController.js">
```

AngularApp.js

```
 debugger;
    angular.module('perica', ['ngRoute']).config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider,  $locationProvider) {

        console.log('in');

            debugger;

            $routeProvider.when('/test', {
            templateUrl: 'views/Account/_Login.html'
    })
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }]);
```

and AccountController.js

```
   var myApp = angular.module('perica', []);
    myApp.controller('AcountController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

     $scope.tagline = 'The square root of life is pi!';
            }]);
```

So as you can see it is a super simple application.

By all the coding logic, I should load angular core scripts the first, then my angular app and at the end angularcontroles.

When I run the app, Chrome hit the first debugger (above angular.module inside AngularApp.js file) and jumped straight into AccountContoler.js and completely ignored what is defined inside of the AngularApp.js.

**but**
When I reversed paths and put first AccountController.js and afterwards AngularApp.js everything worked without any issue

I would be really grateful if someone can shed some light on this issue
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using...

```
var myApp = angular.module('perica', [])
```

... in your `AccountController.js`, you're **not** loading your already existing `'perica'` application (declared in the previously loaded `AngularApp.js`):
you are **re-defining the `perica` application**.

The correct way to refer to your already existing module is using:

```
angular.module('perica')
                       ^
              no dependency declared
```

instead of:

```
angular.module('perica', [])
                         ^
                    dependencies
```

The logic behind this is quite simple once you're acquainted to it: if you're declaring dependencies while "loading" a module, you're **creating** that module. Otherwise, you're **referring** to it.

**TL;DR:** You're basically using a `setter` here **twice** and never actually enhancing your existing module.

---

Here's a [working JSFiddle (link)](https://jsfiddle.net/41yv5g8s/) with your application running. I loaded **AngularJS** directly from the *Javascript framework/extensions* menu and referred to an external JS resource for `angular-route` (fetched from **cdnjs**: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular-route.min.js).

I basically simply concatenated both your `AngularApp.js` and `AccountController.js` contents to emulate loading them one after the other.

---

Please note that your also have to declare the **controller** that controls your view: I took the liberty to enhance your `<body ng-app="perica">` element as follows:

```
<body ng-app="perica" ng-controller="AcountController">
```

Comment: Exactly!!! Such a stupid mistake. Thanks a lot! Now everything works perfectly and of course I need first to reference mainapp.js and afterwards controllers .

Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to have helped you out ;)